# If $V$ is a vector space with finite basis $B$ and $W$ a subspace, then $W ⊆ \operatorname{Span}(B\cap W)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $V$ is a vector space with finite basis $B$ and $W$ a subspace, how to prove that $W= \operatorname{Span}(S)$ where $S=B\cap W$?

How to prove $W ⊆ \operatorname{Span}(S)$? I already proved $\operatorname{Span}(S)⊆W$.

Comment: The claim is false: $\operatorname{Span}(S)\subsetneq W$ is entirely possible, not to mention often the case.

Comment: For a simple example, look at $\mathbb R^2$ with basis $(0,1), (1,0)$.  The one dimensional subspace spanned by $(1,1)$ doesn't contain either basis vector.

Answer (score 1):

$W$ is not equal to $Span(S)$.  Here's a simple disproof.

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$.  Let $W = \{(x,y)| x=0\}$.  Let $B = \{(1,1),(1,-1)\}$.  Then $B$ is a basis for $V$, but no element of $B$ is in $W$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4855682/446262